# Не могу произвести компиляцию в Android Studio!

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, android-studio

Проект пустой! Есть только начальная страница

> Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException:
> > Failed to run command:
> >   C:\Users\Владислав\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat
> > --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Владислав\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
> > --input-list=C:\Users\Владислав\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
> > Error Code:   1 Output:   UNEXPECTED
> > TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >   java.lang.RuntimeException:
> > C:\Users\Р’Р»Р°РґРёСЃР»Р°РІ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug:
> > file not found        at
> > com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> >   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> > C:\Users\Р’Р»Р°РґРёСЃР»Р°РІ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-91748b15a07d05d52886c7ae4f2826f9b5f83ef8.jar
> > (Системе не удается найти указанный
> > путь)         at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native
> > Method)       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
> >       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
> >       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> >   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> > C:\Users\Р’Р»Р°РґРёСЃР»Р°РІ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-7b31c875a07bcd276b6376d6adc59214c7f996f3.jar
> > (Системе не удается найти указанный
> > путь)         at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native
> > Method)       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
> >       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
> >       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> >   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> > C:\Users\Р’Р»Р°РґРёСЃР»Р°РІ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-decb9166fc2dd7eedeaa0fd1f4533f480bad42cd.jar
> > (Системе не удается найти указанный
> > путь)         at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native
> > Method)       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
> >       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
> >       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> >   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> > C:\Users\Р’Р»Р°РґРёСЃР»Р°РІ\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-d5ea6bd1456baa78d5ca6bb657e2e703870a77c4.jar
> > (Системе не удается найти указанный
> > путь)         at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native
> > Method)       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
> >       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
> >       at
> > java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
> >       at
> > com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> >   5 errors; aborting

Comment: Попробуй перемести SDK туда, где в пути не будет кириллицы

Comment: @kvi2994, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно же, что кириллица! Вы видите кракозябры в логах? Исключите кириллицу из путей.

Comment: имя юзера `Владислав` на это ругается студия.

Comment: на самом деле первым про кириллицу подсказал @iksuy...